# Java selenium chromeDriver Timed out как увеличить?

Tags: java, selenium, timeout, chromedriver

Есть страница на которой выполняется кое-какой скрипт и время его выполнения превышает 10мин.
Как только проходит 10мин, выскакивает ошибка:

```
[SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
```

Как увеличить время тайм аута?

Строка:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

не помогает.

Вот мой код:

```
ChromeDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.pathGoogleDriver);
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPathDefault);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Так как в Selenium-е реализовать ожидание можно разными способами, то Вы можете попробовать данные варианты:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

используя неявное/скрытое (Implicit Wait) ожидание.

Для явного ожидания (Explicit Wait), создаёте объект таким образом (пример выполняется в секундах):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence, 15);
```

Для плавного ожидания (Fluent Wait):

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(WebDriver reference)
.withTimeout(15, MINUTES)
.pollingEvery(15, MINUTES)
.ignoring(Exception.class);
```

Кроме того, для решения ошибки:

```
Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer
```

можете проверить совместимость версий у:

- Selenium
- JDK
- ChromeDriver
- Chrome